# G-code for activating material preset in Marlin

Tags: marlin, g-code

Is there a G-code command for calling up the material preset?

I know PLA is set with `M145 S0 H190 B40 F255`: how do I activate `S0`, but not from the LCD menu?

Answer (score 3):

The `M145` G-code command sets the values for the materials for use by the LCD menu solely to preheat the bed and/or hotend and part fan cooling percentage. There is no code to lookup the values and execute to heat up material 1 (`S0`).